# Указатель на указатель. Как получить Size из стринговой переменной

Tags: c++, указатели

Есть такой код:

```
std::string Cat = "Sisko";
std::string *ptrCat = &Cat;
std::string **ptrCat2 = &ptrCat;
```

Как из `ptrCat2` получить `size()` от `Cat`?
Обычный: `*ptrCat2.size()` и `ptrCat2->size()` - не работают.

А размер оригинальной переменной получить нужно.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если у Вас указатель на указатель, так и вытягивайте его дважды.

```
cout << (**ptrCat2).size() <<endl;
```

Comment: Спасибо, не подумал, что нужно заключать в скобки.
Вариант с (*ptr)-> тоже работает.

Comment: конечно работает. Потому что почти всегда `(*ptr).var` эквивалентно `ptr->var` (если только оператор `->` неикто не решил переопределить).

Answer (score 3):

Имеется несколько возможностей задать требуемое выражение. Например,

```
std::cout << (**ptrCat2).size() << std::endl;
std::cout << (*ptrCat2)->size() << std::endl;
std::cout << ptrCat2[0][0].size() << std::endl;
std::cout << ptrCat2[0]->size() << std::endl;
std::cout << ( *ptrCat2[0] ).size() << std::endl;
```

Когда у вас имеется указатель, то имеется два способа разыменовать его. Это либо использовать оператор `*`, как, например,

```
*ptr
```

либо использовать оператор индексации с индексом, равным нулю, как, например,

```
ptr[0]
```

Когда у вас имеется некоторая функция с объявленным параметром, имеющий тип `T **ptr`, где `T` - это некоторый тип, то вы не можете сказать, объект какого типа был передан в качестве аргумента функции.

Допустим, что вы предполагаете, что будет передан массив указателей на массивы (на первые элементы массивов). Спрашивается: можете ли в таком случае определить функцию следующим образом?

```
bool equal(int **ptr, int value)
{
    return ptr[0][0] == value;
}
```

Почему бы и нет? Действительно, данная программа совершенно корректна и читабельна

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

bool equal(int **ptr, int value)
{
    return ptr[0][0] == value;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 10;

    int b[] = { x };
    int * a[] = { b };

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << equal(a, x) << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
true
```

Но эта же функция может быть вызвана, когда имеется не массив указателей на массивы, а массив указателей на скаляры. Например

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

bool equal(int **ptr, int value)
{
    return ptr[0][0] == value;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 10;

    int * a[1] = { &x };

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << equal(a, x) << std::endl;
}
```

Функция успешно выполнит свою работу.

Спрашивается, а надо ли вам переписывать функцию следующим образом

```
bool equal(int **ptr, int value)
{
    return *ptr[0] == value;
}
```

так как элементом массива является указателем на скаляр, а не массив?

Согласно логике одного из комментариев к моему ответу, вас нужно будет "бить по пальцам", если вы этого не сделаете.:)

Но возникает проблема, а что тогда делать с первым типом аргумента из первого примера вызова функции? Нельзя одновременно иметь обе эти функции, так как компилятор выдаст сообщение о неоднозначности.

Но хуже того, функция может быть вызвана для указателя на указатель на скалярный объект!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

bool equal(int **ptr, int value)
{
    return ptr[0][0] == value;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 10;

    int * p = &x;

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << equal(&p, x) << std::endl;
}
```

Функция успешно работает! Но...к этому моменту у вас были бы покалечены все ваши пальцы и вас заставили бы в третий раз переписать функцию следующим образом!:)

```
bool equal(int **ptr, int value)
{
    return **ptr == value;
}
```

Как вы уже, надеюсь, поняли, нет никакой необходимости переписывать функцию. Оба этих два определения функции

```
bool equal(int **ptr, int value)
{
    return ptr[0][0] == value;
}
```

и

```
bool equal(int **ptr, int value)
{
    return **ptr == value;
}
```

эквивалентны и имеют право на существование.

Более того, например, в языке программирования C невозможно отличить выделение динамической памяти для массива  от выделения динамической памяти для скаляра. Если в C++ вы еще можете их различить благодаря различному синтаксису, как показано ниже

```
int *p = new int[1]; // выделяется память для массива
```

и

```
int *p = new int; // выделяется память для скаляра
```

то в C их различить невозможно, так как синтаксически будет одна и та же запись

```
int *p = malloc( sizeof( int ) ); // выделяется память для массива
```

и

```
int *p = malloc( sizeof( int ) ); // выделяется память для скаляра
```

Поэтому как написать функцию `equal`? Вы не сможете различить эти два случая передачи в функцию аргументов, когда в одном случае передается указатель на скаляр, а в другом случае передается указатель на первый элемент массива. Указатели не хранят доступным стандартным образом информацию о том, указывают ли они на скалярный элемент или первый элемент некоторого массива. Поэтому все объявления функции, показанные выше, эквивалентны и имеют право на существование.

Просто вы должны знать, что имеется два способа разыменования указателя. А если кто-то вам пытается "отбить пальцы", то совершенно не факт, что это именно вы делаете что-то неправильно, а не этот кто-то, допустим, просто является программистом с не богатым опытом программирования на C и C++.:)

Comment: Использовать индексацию, когда идёт о сугубо скалярных объектах, это, как минимум, странно.

Comment: @alexolut Ну, вот, вы и расширили свой кругозор в C++.. На самом деле это встречается не редко, так как указатель на любой скалярный объект можно рассматривать как указатель на первый элемент массива, имеющего один элемент.:)

Comment: да как бы мы знаем о этом. Но за подобное в реальном коде нужно бить по пальцам. (вот если бы в примере было сказано, что так можно, но не нужно и приведено равенство `a[b] = b[a] = *(a+b)` - вот тут цены бы не было бы. Кстати, можно и так написать `(0[ptrCat2])->size()`, но кто же так в коде пишет?

Comment: @KoVadim  Так как я имею более 100 тысяч баллов репутации на SO, то я неоднократно сталкивался с тем, что низкоквалифицированные программисты "бьют по рукам" другим, так как им не хватает опыта, но зато самоуверенности хоть отбавляй.:)  Показанные мною примеры, как я уже написал, расширяют кругозор программиста и позволяют ему более уверенно себя чувствовать с указателями.:)

Comment: @KoVadim Эти примеры демонстрируют фундаментальную характеристику указателей, что указатели не хранят в себе информацию о том, указывают ли они на скалярный объект или на первый элемент массива. Это позволяет предотвратить такие ошибки, как вычисление размера массива с помощью указателей, как это часто делают начинающие программисты.:)

Comment: @KoVadim  И почему вы, вдруг, решили, что не может быть такой ситуации, как, например, int * a[N];  int **p = a' ?  Или int **p = new int *; p[0] = new int[N]? Или int **p = new int  *[N]; p[0] = new int;? Я продемонстрировал общий подход, когда имеется указатель на указатель, как обращаться к элементам структурных типов.  В программировании всегда надо стараться обобщать, а не ограничиваться частными случаями. В этом и состоит отдичие квалифицированного программиста от малоквалифицированного.

Comment: очень познавательный пост. Мало того, что мне приписали то, что я не говорил, так ещё код написан на с+, а не с++ (а в метках был он). Но функция, которая будет сравнивать указатель на массив с одним числом (а на самом деле только первый элемент) и называться при этом просто equal? Очень грусно. С другой стороны,  есть контейнеры, но нет, мы будем ручками выдялять память под один int...

Программисты с "богатым опытом" уже наелись и пишут аккуратно. А начинающие, увидев кучу "фич" начинают их тулить без причин, называя себя "квалифицированным".

Comment: @KoVadim Что я вам приписал, что вы не говорили? И в примерах используется массивы из одного элемента просто для простоты. Если вам так очень хочется, вы можете использовать массивы из многих элементов. Суть от этого не меняется.